Looking for a childrens book I read in the early 1990s
I loved a book in the early 90s (in the UK) but was probably published earlier. What I remember is firstly the book was A5 size, similar to a ladybird cover. Hardback but papery textured? Possibly brownish/white/sepia coloured. Story line is along the lines of a girl finding a beat up doll in an antique shop in a box. Owner sells it to her for a couple of pennies. She then meets the original owner, an elderly lady. They become friends and have doll tea parties with the ladies other vintage dolls. The name Clara or Clara Belle is coming to mind also?

"Tea at Mrs. Manderby's" by Adèle Geras
From Growing Point Volume 15, 1976:

Hannah dislikes being taken to tea with the old lady along the road;
politeness is irksome, the valuable china is alarmingly thin and Mrs.
Manderby always seems stern and distant. Only the comfort of a new
doll, a battered  object bought at the junk shop with her savings,
consoles Hannah for one more tea-party - until the surprising moment
when it turns out that Belle is really Mrs. Manderby's own Clara,
given away fifty years before. And so the next day there is another
tea-party, relaxed and happy, with dolls as guests and in the garden
instead of the drawing-room.

